# How to insert figures from files to matplotlib white window?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

How to add to matplotlib figures from file with the possibility to set the size of the inserted figure, rotation, and position?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure, axis = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you elaborate and provide additional context in the workflow you're like to execute?

Comment: I have several pictures - files, and I would like to consolidate into one figure. I would like to set for all pictures a position, rotation, and size.

Comment: pictures as in exported plots? pictures as in photographs of cat and dogs doing funny things? pictures as in raster images that you're analyzing? be specific. show an example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have several png pictures generated by python (matplotlib)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/images.html

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-advanced-transforms-tutorial-py

Comment: My recommendation would be to turn what ever code you used to generate those plots into functions, then apply to functions to axes laid out on a figure with e.g., `pyplot.subplots`